# Convert a function output in a URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, filter

I'm not sure if I'm asking this properly. I'm working on a Wordpress site using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).

I have this function:

```
<?php the_sub_field('block_title'); ?>
```

That returns results like "Home", "About Us", "Contact Us".

I would like to know if there's a way to convert this output to a URL like format such as "about-us", "contact-us" so I can go ahead and construct some anchor links.

I'm not sure how to search for this over Google so I'm kind of lost

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

The output I'm trying to attempt is something like this:

```
<li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></li>
```

The code so far is:

```
<li><a href="#<?php sanitize_title( the_sub_field('block_title') ); ?>  "><?php the_sub_field('block_title'); ?></a></li>
```

But the result is:

```
<li><a href="About Us">About Us</a></li>
```

Comment: you need to search google for `how to convert text to slug in wordpress`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Getting there: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

Comment: Add echo before sanitize_title(.... or change <?php to <?=

Comment: Still the same output. I think the ACF plugin must be doing something on top of it.

Comment: test your code with `<?php echo sanitize_title( "this is a test" ); ?>`

Comment: It outputs "this-is-a-test" so definitely there's something going on with the ACF plugin

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has a function for this `sanitize_title`

```
 sanitize_title( the_sub_field('block_title') );
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title

Comment: Thanks @Shujaat. I think this is what I'm looking for (based on the Wordpress documentation. However I tried your code and it does not seem to work. The output is still the same. That subfield function comes from a plugin called ACF (maybe that's the reason?)

Comment: do you echo or save it to a variable ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correct but is this what you looking for?

```
strtolower( str_replace(' ', '-', the_sub_field('block_title')) );
```

Comment: Almost! But it seems this is used only for converting characters to lowercase.

Comment: What else do you want to convert to lowercase? Regardless, you should use sanitize_title() since the function already exists in WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you guys helped me get in the right path.

The solution was using "sanitize_title". Working code is:

```
<?php echo sanitize_title(get_sub_field('block_title')); ?>
```

Thanks!